# Why does this if statement give an output despite the && conditions not being satisfied?

Tags: matlab, syntax, short-circuiting, logical-and

I have been trying to execute a piece of code with some if conditions. This is a simple version of it.

```
X=100;Y=100;
if ((((X+1) && (Y+1))<=99) && (((X+1) && (Y+1))<=102))
    disp(X);
end
```

Despite both X and Y not satisfying the first condition, I still get the output as 100. I have tried all combinations of & and && to make the and operations in the work. I checked the difference between the two and I found that & is a logical bit-wise operator while && is a short-circuit operator, which probably doesn't change much in this context. What's the error with this syntax?

Of course the code works when I do this:

```
X=100;Y=100;
if (X+1)<=99 && (Y+1)<=99 && (((X+1) && (Y+1))<=102)
    disp(X);
end
```

But this is so inefficient when there are lot of conditions and each sub-condition must include the constraints. I'm sure this must be answered somewhere and this question might be a duplicate, so please point me to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you understand what `(X+1)<=99 && (Y+1)<=99` does. Let's look at `((X+1) && (Y+1))<=99`:

`&&` requires a logical value on each side. `a && b` will turn `a` and `b` into logicals, effectively becoming `a~=0 && b~=0`. Thus:

```
((X+1)    && (Y+1)   ) <= 99
((X+1)~=0 && (Y+1)~=0) <= 99
( true    &&  true   ) <= 99
           1           <= 99
                      true
```

Of course the truth value of `(X+1)~=0` and `(Y+1)~=0` could be different, but here you see this. In MATLAB, `true` is equal to `1` in a non-logical context, as when compared to `99`.

---

If you want to simplify this expression, use `max` instead of `&&`:

```
X=100;Y=100;
if max(X+1,Y+1)<=99 && max(X+1,Y+1)<=102
    disp(X);
end
```

If the max of `a` and `b` is smaller than `99`, then both `a` and `b` are smaller than `99`.

(Obviously, the statement can be further simplified to `if max(X+1,Y+1)<=102`, since if the second inequality holds than so must the first.)

Comment: Why does the if condition not work even when I swap && with &? Does it work the same way with &?

Comment: @Matte: Yes, it works the same way. `&` and `&&` differ in that `&` works on matrices element-wise, and `&&` works on scalars, with guaranteed short-circuiting behaviour. But they both do a Boolean operation on Boolean inputs, and convert their inputs to `logical` if necessary.